# Sending vars from a classic ASP page to Flash using AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, asp-classic

I am having a bit of trouble retrieving variables from an ASP page. It returns the entire page whereas I just need the variable strAnswer from the page. Please help?

Here is my code:

```
        var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onDataSaved);
        loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;

        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://" + host + urlPath + "setXML.asp");
        request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

        var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        variables.xmlString = str;
        variables.eltGuid = eltGuid;
        request.data = variables;

        loader.load(request);


    private function onDataSaved(e:Event):void 
    {
        var loader2:URLLoader = URLLoader(e.target);
        loader2.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
        trace(loader2.data.strAnswer);

    }
```

ASP Page:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<% 

Response.CacheControl = "no-cache" 
Response.AddHeader "Pragma", "no-cache"
Response.Expires = -1
%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1    /DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>setASP</title>
</head>

<body>
<%

Dim xmlBlock, strEltGuid, objRQL
xmlBlock = escape(Request.Form("xmlString"))
strEltGuid = Request.Form("eltGuid")

'---------------------------
'Post to RedDot CMS via RQL
'---------------------------

Set objRQL = Server.CreateObject("RDCMSASP.RdPageData")
objRQL.XMLServerClassname = "RDCMSServer.XmlServer"
xmlData = "<IODATA loginguid=" & Chr(34) & Session("LoginGuid") & Chr(34) &  " format=" & Chr(34) & "1" & Chr(34) & " sessionkey=" & Chr(34) & Session("SessionKey") & Chr(34) & "><ELT translationmode='0' extendedinfo='' reddotcacheguid='' action='save' guid='" & strEltGuid & "' pageid='' id='' index='' type='31'>" & xmlBlock & "</ELT></IODATA>"
'Response.Write(xmlBlock)
'Response.Write(strEltGuid)
objRQL.ServerExecuteXML xmlData, rqlError
If rqlError <> "" Then
Response.Write rqlError
Else
strAnswer = "strResponse=Just a test!   How strange. ..."
Response.Write (strAnswer)
'Response.Write "strResponse=Just a test!   How strange. ..."
'Response.Write      "Saved successfully."          '"Saved     successfully."                              '
End If

'Response.Write "strResponse=Just a test!   How strange. ..."


'------------------
'Be a good citizen
'------------------

Set objRQL = Nothing

%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what language are you using in this classic ASP page ?

Comment: I am using classic asp as the language in the asp page.

Comment: I'm sorry, the language is vbscript

Comment: I've went ahead and added the asp page. thanks for your help

Comment: have you run the asp page by itself to see if it completing ?

Comment: Yes, I ran the page. it processes correctly

Comment: christophe answer below is correct you will need to remove all html language from your ASP page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating and loading an html page. If you remove all of the html tags and just use Response.Write to output the variable, that should work.

I used to do this a lot in the past to load dynamically generated XML from ASP into Flash. I have blog post about this here: http://www.herrodius.com/blog/18